# The meaning of Sprague-Grundy ordinal

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

I have an unusual request to you. I speak English badly (I'm from Russia). Май инглиш из вери бед (sorry, Russian stupid joke).
I'm writing a term paper. I faced with the problem of translation of mathematical terms with the English. Could you please help me?
My course work related to the theory of combinatorial games.
Please explain what "Sprague-Grundy ordinal" from the text: 
" The value of 'g' cannot increase as moves are added, and at most finitely many legal moves preserve the value of 'g'. Thus every position has a well-defined Sprague-Grundy ordinal, which may be transfinite. "

Comment: Try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem). Search for the word "ordinal" in the page.

Comment: Your English is not very bad (I can read a little Cyrillic but not Russian, so your joke was easy to understand). Sprague-Grundy ordinals are [nimbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimber) (a play on the game *Nim* and the word *numbers*, with an *i* rather than *u*), the values of impartial combinatorial games. Your quote is from an article on *Sylver Coinage*, another play on words

Answer (score 2):

Вы просто хотите *перевод* фразы с английского (кстати, «с» плюс родительный, например «с английского», значит from не with) или Вы хотите *определение* слова? У Вас нет книги о комбинаторных играх?

(Позже) По Гуглу, фраза Sprague-Grundy ordinal возникает только в статье, которую Вы читаете (она написана 13 лет назад), и на этой странице. Поэтому это нестандартная фраза. Я читал несколько страниц в интернете, и насколько я знаю термин Sprague-Grundy ordinal значит нимбер, т.е., я согласен с замечанием использователя Henry. Нимберы являются множеством порядковых чисел с новым типом сложения и умножения, наверно Вы уже знаете о них, если Вы занимаетесь теорией игр. Такой перевод имеет смысл?

Comment: Ой, я могу ошибаться. Спасибо за поправку моей ошибки.

Comment: Мне нужен грамотный перевод этого термина и что он вообще значит, то есть его определение.

Comment: У меня есть книги на русском языке, у меня именно проблемы с переводом математических терминов.

Comment: KCd, кстати, о игре "Sylver Coinage" нет книг на русском языке, поэтому мне приходится переводить с английского языка.

Comment: @Shahar, what in the world are you talking about?

Comment: От какого источника возникает Ваш вопрос?

Comment: Прочитали ли Вы страницу на Википедии о функции Шпрага-Гранди? Не знаю, если на той странице находится ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: И кант спэак Руссиан

Comment: Спасибо большое! Да, я прочитала статью. Вы мне очень помогли! Добрые американские люди)))

Comment: Ясно ли откуда я? Не знал, что я пишу с американским (не английским, австралийским, канадским, и т.д.) акцентом.

Comment: Для нас в России все, кто говорит на английском - американцы ))) Sorry

Comment: Интересно. Я не имел в виду, что Вы не правы. На самом деле, Вы правы.

Comment: Вопрос не в тему: здесь на сайте есть функция личных сообщений?

Comment: Здесь нет такой функции. Смотрите http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/how-to-contact-a-specific-user-is-there-any-sort-of-pm-private-message-fa.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is, but I think it might hinge on the word ordinal which used since sprague-grundy values are nimbers, not numbers in the ordinary sense.  For example the nimber *2 is its own negative *2 +*2=*0.  Look at the wikipedia article on sprague-grundy for a nice explanation.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprague%E2%80%93Grundy_theorem